# How to put text behind user output on html/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, what I'm trying to do is get it to say "hello, [name]" - I thought that running two onclick events via javascript would work, but it only refers to the second function while ignoring my "greet" function... Here is the code in question;

```
        <button id = "submit" onclick = "greet();">SUBMIT</button>

        <p id = para001></p>

        <script>
            function greet() {
                document.getElementById("para001").innerHTML = "Hello,"
                return document.getElementById(objID).value;
            }

            function getName() {
               
               let txtRef = document.getElementById("nametxt");
               let pRef = document.getElementById("para001");
               pRef.innerHTML = txtRef.value;
               pRef.innerHTML = getval("nametxt");
           }
        </script>
```

Comment: where is `getval`?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this on your function greet()

```
function greet() {
                let returnText = "Hello, " + document.getElementById("nametxt").value;
                document.getElementById("para001").innerHTML = returnText;
                return document.getElementById(objID).value;
            }
```